# Interpreting Machine Learning Classification Metrics

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand the results of a classifier I used to predict two possible classes. Here is what I get:

```
     Precision     Recall     F1-score     Support

 0      0.97        1.00        0.98        341091
 1      0.60        0.18        0.27        12629

 Avg    0.96        0.97        0.96        353720
```

If I'm trying to predict Class 1, does this model have any value? Can I improve the results of Class 1 prediction?

Comment: It sounds like you need a primer on these terms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classification report shows that your estimator is good at recognizing class 0 (both precision and recall are close to 1 as is the f1-score, which is combination of both). However it fails for class 1.

This can be caused by using an estimator (or its parametrization) that is sensitive to not-balanced dataset. Look at the support -- there is almost 30-times more examples of the class 0 than the class 1! Many scikit-learn estimators have parameter to compensate this imbalance during training (or allow you to assign weights to the training samples (e.g., give higher weights to less frequent samples of class 1), so that the importance of the few examples of class 1 is raised.

Imagine an extreme case with classifier that always answers 0. For class 0 it would have recall 1 (all class 0 samples discovered) and precision 0.96 (= 341091 / 353720). For class 1 the precision would be ill-defined and recall would be 0. However the overall accuracy would be 0.96 (341091 correctly recognized cases out of 353720). By the way this shows that accuracy is not a good metric for imbalanced sets.

Comment: I want to raise the issue that you should not be treating soft classification models (i.e. ones that are intended to predict a probability) as hard classification models by thresholding at 0.5.  If you are, for example, using the `predict` method in sklearn for a classifier, you should not be doing that.  It is imperative in any decision scenario to take care at how one thresholds their probabilities to assign classes.  This is a more important concern to address than the class balancing (1/30 is not really an extreme ratio).

Comment: I would say, that if you have an estimator that predicts probabilities, then you should assign classes by the highest probability (i.e., use argmax, not any kind of thresholding). Anyway, I do not find this related to the original question, as we do not know anything about the used estimator.

Comment: That is not correct as a blanket statement.  In any real life problem we are making class assignments to meet some goal, i.e. we are making them to aid us in a decision making process.  This means there are costs to errors and successes of various types, and these must be taken into account when deciding what actions to make.  It is very rare that our goal is actually making correct class assignments, we always want to make the best decisions to accomplish some goals.  Often these decisions do not align with the most probable class from some model.